# Not seeing post data in node server

Tags: ajax, node.js, post

While making below ajax call, I am not seeing any post data in node server side.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.origin + "/api/books",
    data: {
        title: "Javascript some good partd",
        author: "Douglas crockford",
        releaseDate: new Date(2013, 4, 2).getTime()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

After doing some search, I found out it could be because of body-parser configuration but unable to get it right. Please find below the node server configuration.

```
app.configure( function() {
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'site')));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true}));
});
```

And API call is:

```
app.post('/api/books', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var book = new BookModel({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        releaseDate: req.body.releaseDate
    });
    return book.save(function (err, response) {
        if (!err) {
          return res.send(book);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

req.body is logged as undefined. Can anyone please help on debugging the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the app.configure function.

All the code inside of it can be left floating in that file.

My best guess would be that its not firing off that function.

I tend to use this code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Thanks dsharris!! I was able to get it working with this code.